How can I select and remove excess loops from an edge outline using python?
How can I select these vertices in this weird loops encircled in red using python? In this example I only have 5 vertices excess but it's possible for more or lesser vertices to be junctioned like that.

Or any solution for a filled mesh:


How would you characterize such "excess loops" ? Do you have something like "protruding inside/outside" ? Or is it a "path" ?

its just flat on the XY plane. and all edges are connected to the same common vertex. I feared it's probably not possible because it seems there is no way to characterize such excess loop.

It is possible. 100+ lines of code to write and debug. Recursively traversing the mesh using bmesh and link_edges, detect and delete loops that longer than some amount of verts.

yup that's exactly what i thought. i meant not possible in simple terms though haha. thanks alot for your feedback! but maybe its possible with a few lines to check for loops that are smaller than 10 edges. so basically it will check for junction vertices with 4 edges connected to them and then check only up to 10 linked edges which is longer to traverse. shouldnt be too computationally expensive?

Did something alike lately https://gist.github.com/unwave/7d360719853b67d7a1735700a34b2b6e, I think you will still have to make a walker that will check all the vertices.

@unwave i found the solution. So initially this shape had faces which i removed. So before I remove those faces, I just extrude it temporarily then i can do select "Interior" faces and it selects these parts.

Found the solution. Just extrude the mesh and then you can do Select Interior Faces. And then unextrude.
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
obj.select_set(True)
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_region_move(TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(0, 0, 0.01)})
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_interior_faces()
bpy.ops.mesh.delete(type='FACE')
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

mesh = obj.data
for face in mesh.polygons:
    normal = obj.matrix_world @ face.normal
    if normal.z > 0:
        face.select = True
        break

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_similar(type='FACE_NORMAL', threshold=0.01)
bpy.ops.mesh.delete(type='VERT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.mesh.normals_make_consistent(inside=True)


